Android webview, Access image data from image loaded in website without making Java request
How do I get the image data from an image that is loaded in a webpage in Android webview? (Not just the link URL, the actual data.) The kicker is that I need to do this without making a second request from the Java side of things. All requests have to be made from the webpage. Ideally, I'd like to do this without user interaction, but it would be acceptable if that was the only way.
Some thoughts and things I tried:
1. Implement a context menu with copy image option
This would be like in Chrome: longpress > "Copy image". However, all I'm able to get from this is the image URL. Is there a way to get the image data? Again, making a Java request using the URL is not an option. I tested that Chrome does not make a second request to the image URL so this is possible, but I don't know how. Also, not ideal because of the user interaction required, but would be acceptable.
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(contextMenu, view, contextMenuInfo);

        final WebView.HitTestResult webViewHitTestResult = webView.getHitTestResult();

        if (webViewHitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE || webViewHitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

            contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Image options");

            contextMenu.add(0, 1, 0, "Get image")
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                            // I want image data, not the URL
                            String DownloadImageURL = webViewHitTestResult.getExtra();

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

2. Inject javascript to get image data from canvas
The idea is to load the image into a canvas, then get the image data from the canvas. (Making a second request to the image URL from the webpage itself would be OK.) However, this doesn't work because I get a "tainted canvas" error. I can control the website (to some degree) but cannot change the cross-origin permissions of the image cdn.
3. Directly access the image from wherever it is cached
This would be ideal, but I don't know how, or if it's even possible. If an image is loaded in a webpage, can I access just that cached image? How would I identify it? (I know the link URL.) And, once again, requesting the image in Java and saving that file to cache is not an option. Any image URL requests must come from the webpage.

Similar to: Get all images from a WebView in Android

Chrome is an app with access it own cache. WebViews are self-contained system components with a limited API to exist within your app. While your ask is like WebView load website when online, load local file when offline Android has made changes such that possibly relevant APIs like setAppCachePath and setAppCacheEnabled these are not work in android 33.

Thanks! I guess it's not possible. I also see that Firefox makes a new call to the image URL when I choose the copy image option.
